# Getting the total of a division measure to display the sum of that column

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a measure in powerbi that takes the sum of 2 columns and divides them to give me a a value for each row. At the moment the total at the bottom takes the total sum of both those columns and divides them together to give me a decimal value. Is there a way to get the total to display the sum of the answer of the divisions rather than the value of both totals divided?

I've tried splitting it down into smaller chunks using calc columns.

```
Total Missed Calls Divide =
      SUM ( 'dwvw CC_ContactTraceRecords'[Contacts missed] )
    / SUM ( 'dwvw CC_ContactTraceRecords'[Total Calls Without Filter] )
```

I want to see to sum of all the divisions in the total.

Comment: perhaps adding your table and it's column with values and desired result would be helpful to provide you with ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This comes down to what attributes you are using in your Rows, I will assume you are using only one column, lets say *Customer[Customer]*.

You can adjust your measure to:

```
Total Missed Calls Divide (Customer) = 
    SUMX(
        VALUES(Customer[Customer])
        ,DIVIDE(
             SUM('dwvw CC_ContactTraceRecords'[Contacts missed])
             ,SUM('dwvw CC_ContactTraceRecords'[Total Calls Without Filter])
        )
    )
```

Also try to use the *DIVIDE* function instead of explicit divide operator */*